# get element with n children

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

i have the following HTML

```html
<li data-testid="wrapper">
  <div class="selections">
    <p data-testid="selection1">
    <p data-testid="selection2">
    <p data-testid="selection3">
    ...
    <p data-testid="selectionN">

  </div>
  <button type="button" data-testid="button"></button>
  </li>
```

there are multiple wrappers with different amount of selections. I want to click the button on the first wrapper with exactly 3 selections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply a `.filter()` with a jQuery expression:

```js
cy.get('li[data-testid="wrapper"]')
  .filter((i,li) => Cypress.$(li).find('p').length === 3 )
  .first()
  .click()
```

These alternatives also work:

```js
.filter((i,li) => Cypress.$(li).find('.selections').children().length === 3 )
.filter((i,li) => Cypress.$(li).find('[data-testid^="selection"]').length === 3 )
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is what you want?

Scan through all wrappers, check how many `<p>` each has.

```js
cy.get('li[data-testid="wrapper"]')
  .each($li => {
    const $p = $li.find('p')
    if ($p.length === 3) {
      cy.wrap($li).find('button').click()

      return false;  // perform an early exit 
                     // since you only want one item clicked 
    }
  })
```

Comment: this will click on all elements with 3 children, not the first

Comment: If you only want one click, perform an early exit.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a bit of js after selecting each wrapper

```js
const wrappers = [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-testid=wrapper]')];
const firstWrapperWith3Selections = wrappers.find((w) => w.querySelector(".selections").children.length === 3);
console.log(firstWrapperWith3Selections);
firstWrapperWith3Selections.style.backgroundColor = "red";
firstWrapperWith3Selections.querySelector("button").click();
```

```html
<ul>
<li data-testid="wrapper">
  <div class="selections">
    <p data-testid="selection1">
    <p data-testid="selection2">
  </div>
  <button type="button" data-testid="button"></button>
</li>
<li data-testid="wrapper">
  <div class="selections">
    <p data-testid="selection1">
  </div>
  <button type="button" data-testid="button"></button>
</li>
<li data-testid="wrapper">
  <div class="selections">
    <p data-testid="selection1">
    <p data-testid="selection2">
    <p data-testid="selection3">
  </div>
  <button type="button" data-testid="button"></button>
</li>
<li data-testid="wrapper">
  <div class="selections">
    <p data-testid="selection1">
    <p data-testid="selection2">
    <p data-testid="selection3">
    <p data-testid="selection4">
  </div>
  <button type="button" data-testid="button"></button>
</li>
<li data-testid="wrapper">
  <div class="selections">
    <p data-testid="selection1">
    <p data-testid="selection2">
    <p data-testid="selection3">
    <p data-testid="selection4">
  </div>
  <button type="button" data-testid="button"></button>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const wrappers = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper")

wrappers[0].addEventListener('click',()=>{
//Whatever you want to run // for Example :'function()'
//You must add that function to your button so whenever you click that wrapper button will work.})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).